# What does **The introduction into curricula of education about** mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Ran into this complex sentence:

> **The introduction into curricula of education about** the value of tourist exchanges, their economic, social and cultural benefits, and also their risks, should be encouraged;(Source: Global code of ethics for tourism)

What does **The introduction into curricula of education about** mean? Does it mean **Trying to teach about**? Would you please rephrase it?
Moreover, Would someone kindly rephrase the whole sentence? What is it trying to convey?

I find the English of the whole Code a bit not-fluent and complex. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 'mis-bracketed' the pieces of this sentence. It works like this

> The introduction of education should be encouraged. = *Somebody should encourage people to introduce education = to bring education into something*
>
> *Introduce education where? Bring it into what?* —Introduce education **into curricula**.
>    Bring it into the formal schedules of courses and their content.)
>
> *What kind of education?* —Education **about the value of tourist exchanges,
>
>     their economic, social and cultural benefits, and also their risks**

We should encourage the people in charge of education to put teaching about these important subjects into their courses.

Comment: Wow! So if I am not mistaken the sentence is *The introduction(covering, including) of education(knowledge) about the value of tourist exchanges, their economic, social and cultural benefits, and also their risks into curricula(of schools) should be encouraged.* Am I right, sir?

Comment: @Juya, mostly, except *introduce into* does not mean to provide a preliminary account but to bring something new into a situation -- to make this new subject matter a part of the curriculum.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me what *tourist exchanges* mean? looks like it means receiving tourist from other countries and sending tourist to other countries. Am I right?

Comment: @Juya It's probably not a matter of a formal exchange directed by governments but the flow of tourists in both directions.